# DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI Intermittent

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have an intermittent problem with `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()`

The code actually works fine all all my screens except my first screen. If I run my app in VS2013 in the emulator the first screen works fine every time. The same if I run in debug connected to yy Lumia 930, most of the time it works.

However If I run on my 930 standalone the function rarely works on the first page, nothing happens when I click the button, no error, nothing. Like I say all the other pages, no problem

My app has 8 xaml pages and all those with the `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI` in work perfectly every time. My main page though is the problem and its the exact same code.

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        // Register the current page as a share source.
        _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
    }
}

protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "MyTitle";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = sDescription
    e.Request.Data.SetText("My text");
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Unregister the current page as a share source.
    if (_dataTransferManager != null)
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
}

private void ShareTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

I've checked various articles on here and most deal with this problem not working at all. Help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write this piece of code in the page constructor and try.

```
_dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
_dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
```

Comment: Yes that seems to be it. Weird those I never noticed that was the problem lol.